# How to print float value with two decimal and without decimal in java

Tags: java, android

This is my code

```
 float realvalue = 7.5
  worthValue = "£" + String.format(String.valueOf(value - (float) .50));
```

I want to display values like this if realvalue will 7.5 then it should display worthValue  7 while when realvalue is 8 then it should display worthValue 7.50 please help me in this how-to display with and without decimal of float value

Comment: why not use BigDecimal

Comment: can you show the expected output and the output you are getting .

Comment: expected output if difference 7.5 and 7.0  then it should display £7.50 and £7 respectively my actual is £7.5 and £7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
String worthValue;
float realValue = 8f;
if (realValue % 1 == 0f) {
    worthValue = String.format("£ %.2f", realValue - 0.5);
} else {
    worthValue = String.format("£ %d", (int) (realValue - 0.5));
}
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormatter to format your value like this.

```
DecimalFormat paymentFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.##");
paymentFormatter.format(input);
```

Comment: float realvalue = (float) 7.5;
        DecimalFormat paymentFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.##");
        paymentFormatter.format(realvalue - (float) .50);
       String worthValue = "£" + String.format(String.valueOf(paymentFormatter));
        textView.setText(worthValue); i tried like this not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static String format(float f) {
    String r = String.format("%.2f", f);
    if (r.endsWith(".00"))
        return r.substring(0, r.length() - 3);
    return r;
}
```

And

```
float realValue1 = 7.5f;
System.out.println("£" + format(realValue1 - 0.5f));
float realValue2 = 8.0f;
System.out.println("£" + format(realValue2 - 0.5f));
```

Results:

```
£7
£7.50
```